# Maximum file Upload

Tags: php, uploads, php.ini

I want to ask the about this upload_max_filesize = 2M in PHP. Does it mean that the allowable file upload is 2M? then how could we or how can we upload videos more than 2M?. Thanks new to PHP.

Comment: You can't. If you want to upload larger files, increase the max filesize.

Comment: @JacobPeattie, should we based on our hosting provider for the capacity?